# Excel 2007 Unique Cells in separate sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have Sheet A that has Names in Column 1.  I also have Sheet B that has names in Column 2.  I am wanting to compare both columns to see if there are names in Sheet A that does not match Sheet B and names on Sheet B that does not match Sheet A.  I am trying to highlight the names on each sheet that does not match.  I've tried using the conditional formatting tab with no luck.  I know that this is probably real simple, but I'm struggling with it. Can someone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

`=if(ISERROR(MATCH(OneCellInColumn1,Column2,0)),"Missing","Present")`

Add this next to each name, on both sheets.

Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

In SheetA:

```
=MATCH(A1,SheetB!B:B,0)
```

in SheetB:

```
=MATCH(B1,SheetA!A:A,0)
```

and both copied down to suit shoud return either a numeric value (it would be the position of the (first instance of) any match in the "other sheet) or `#N/A`.

Each sheet might then be filtered to select rows containing `#N/A` in the relevant column and then highlighting applied to suit.